# Update table from a table while joining on a column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alias, sql-update

I apologize that my SQL Kung Fu isn't up to par, but this seems like a basic task that I can't seem to complete.

I've got two tables in Sql Server 2008

tblBoxAddress
--Address
--Zip
--Latitude
--Longitude

tblUpdatedDated
--Address
--latitude
--longitude

I have to update the latitude and longitude of tblBoxAddress with the lat. and long. from tblUpdatedData by matching on the address.  The problem is that tblUpdatedData.Address contains the zip code.  In tblBoxAddress, this is broken into two separate columns.

I've been able to make a select statement work correctly

```
select * from tblUpdatedData t
inner join (
Select Address + ' ' + zip As 'full_address', Latitude, Longitude from tblBoxAddress) d
on d.full_address = t.Address
```

However, I can't figure out how to combine the address and zip of tblBoxAddress on an update statement.  This was as far as I've gotten:

```
update d
set d.Latitude = t.latitude, d.Longitude = t.longitude
FROM tblBoxAddress d inner join 
tblUpdatedData t on t.Address = d.Address + ' ' + d.zip as 'full_address'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Comment: SQL Server 2008, i'll update my question with that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to alias in the update clause(s). e.g. try:

```
update d
set d.Latitude = t.latitude, d.Longitude = t.longitude
FROM tblBoxAddress d inner join 
tblUpdatedData t on t.Address = d.Address + ' ' + d.zip;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try it in the morning when I'm back at work and I'll make sure to mark your answer as correct if it works (which it will) :)